# Marquesinas o <marquee>, ¿Como hacer una marquesina con el texto siempre visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero hacer una marquesina algo diferente, el texto se desplaza de un lado a otro y cuando termina de esconderse por un lado aparece por el otro, lo que deseo es que al momento de llegar a un extremo aparezca denuevo el mismo texto por el otro lado, antes de que el texto termine de esconderse, es posible hacer eso?

```html
<marquee bgcolor= "#0000" style="color:white;" >Quiero que este texto sea siempre visible y aparezca antes de terminar</marquee>
```

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?... mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Qué más debe añadir el OP?

Comment: El elemento [`marquee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMarqueeElement) es muy limitado y poco extensible. Tal vez usando Javascript puedas conseguir lo que te propones. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo solo con CSS así:

- Creamos un contenedor `.marquee`
- Dentro del `.marquee`, creamos un elemento `.wrapper` que ocupa el 200% del ancho
- Dentro del `.wrapper`, creamos 2 elementos que cada uno ocupa el 50%.
- Utilizando [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) hacemos que el elemento `.wrapper` se muevan de derecha a izquierda.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
}

.marquee .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200%;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee .wrapper div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>Quiero que este texto sea siempre visible y aparezca antes de terminar</div>
    <div>Quiero que este texto sea siempre visible y aparezca antes de terminar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```